# Direct speech to Indirect speech

Tags: reported-speech

> A man says, " **May I drop you there in my car?**"

Convert the above sentence to reported speech.

*Is the following a correct attempt?*

> **A man asked if he might drop somebody there in his car.**

---

---

*Not a native English speaker*

Comment: First, you try. Then explain why you think your attempt is wrong. It would be helpful to know who is the man **offering** to give a lift to..

Comment: Let's assume it as his friend.

Comment: Your attempt is not bad but you have modified the meaning, *may* and *should* are not synonymous. What is the "past" equivalent of "may"?

Comment: So is it might?

Comment: Is the the above correct now?

Comment: It's nearly perfect. If no one posts an answer by tonight I will.

Comment: As I see it, the only problem in the translation is that in the direct speech *you* has no gender. You are *assuming* that the person being dropped is a man. If the person being dropped is a woman, then the translation is incorrect. In other words, the version in indirect speech is introducing a variable that never existed. You need to replace *him* with something non-gender specific—such as *somebody*.

Comment: Ahh, you edited the indirect sentence. I was remembering the original one. Well, now it's pretty much perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To transform direct speech into indirect (also called *reported speech*), the learner has to remember several things. First of all, remove the speech/quotation marks (also called *inverted commas*). Then…

1. **Change the pronouns**

- Fiona asked John, "Can **I** tell **you** a secret?"
- Fiona asked John if **she** could tell **him** a secret.

2. **[backshift](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm) the verbs**

- Fiona **asks** John, "**Can** I tell you a secret?"
- Fiona **asked** John if she **could** tell him a secret.

3. **Backshift a [time reference](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-time-place.htm) if it is mentioned**

- "I have something important to tell you **today**", said Fiona.
- Fiona said she had something important to tell him **that day**

4. **Use a reporting verb**

The most common reporting verbs are *say/said* and *tell/told* but there are many others which the learner can use to add some variety

If the direct speech is a question, use the reporting verb **ask**.

If the direct speech has "would", we can use the reporting verb **invite**
e.g. a) *"Would you like me to drop you there?"* b) *He invited to drop her/him/them there.*

If the speaker uses the modals “can”, “may”, “shall/will”, we can use the reporting verb **offer**
e.g. a) *“Can/May/Shall I help you?”* b) *She offered to help her/him/them/someone*

If  the object of the sentence is unknown, use the impersonal pronoun ***someone***. But be careful, the pronoun "you" can either refer to the *singular* or *plural*. For example, I might be talking to one person, a couple or to a large group of people.

> “Do **you** need help?” Marilou said.

Is Marilou talking to one person or to several?

Thus the OP's direct speech sentence

> A man says, "May I drop you there in my car?"

can be changed into this

> A man offered to drop someone there in his car

or the singular [*they*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192/is-it-correct-to-use-their-instead-of-his-or-her/208#208) and its equivalent pronoun object can be used instead

> He said he might drop **them** there in his car

or even this

> A man asked if he might drop that person there (e.g. at the station) in his car

Comment: @Kaushik my pleasure, I hope the answer was still helpful to you.